# "\\" turn into "\\\\" when printing a list of filepath stored in csv file

Tags: python, csv

I want to get a list of img filepath dictionary stored in a csv file, like this:
 
And this is a picture of my csv file output in excel:
[image: input]

And here is my code:

```py
def read_cell(filelocation,column_name,row_index):
    with open(filelocation, 'r',encoding="utf8") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f,delimiter=',')
        y_count = 1
        for n in reader:
            if y_count == row_index:
                cell = n[column_name]
                return cell
            y_count += 1

id_item="1812242028"
img_list_query=[]
for row in range(100):
    product_id=read_cell(img_file,"PRODUCT_ID",row)
    if product_id==id_item:
        img_list_query.append(read_cell(img_file,"IMG_FILE_NAME",row))
print(img_list_query)
```

And the result of above code:

```
['C:\\\\Users\\\\admin\\\\Desktop\\\\set-5-goi-mat-na-trai-cay-duong-da-real-nature-mask_0', 'C:\\\\Users\\\\admin\\\\Desktop\\\\set-5-goi-mat-na-trai-cay-duong-da-real-nature-mask_1', 'C:\\\\Users\\\\admin\\\\Desktop\\\\set-5-goi-mat-na-trai-cay-duong-da-real-nature-mask_2', 'C:\\\\Users\\\\admin\\\\Desktop\\\\set-5-goi-mat-na-trai-cay-duong-da-real-nature-mask_3', 'C:\\\\Users\\\\admin\\\\Desktop\\\\set-5-goi-mat-na-trai-cay-duong-da-real-nature-mask_4', 'C:\\\\Users\\\\admin\\\\Desktop\\\\set-5-goi-mat-na-trai-cay-duong-da-real-nature-mask_5', 'C:\\\\Users\\\\admin\\\\Desktop\\\\set-5-goi-mat-na-trai-cay-duong-da-real-nature-mask_6', 'C:\\\\Users\\\\admin\\\\Desktop\\\\set-5-goi-mat-na-trai-cay-duong-da-real-nature-mask_7', 'C:\\\\Users\\\\admin\\\\Desktop\\\\set-5-goi-mat-na-trai-cay-duong-da-real-nature-mask_8']
```

I do not know why "\" turn into "\\"?

Pls, give me some explaintion about this problem and solution for it? thanks!

Comment: The string `'\\'` translates to \. Every backslash is preceded by a backslash in order to prevent it from being used as a special character along with the character which follows it. For example, if you want to represent the string `\n`, then you'd use `'\\n'` and not `'\n'`, because the latter represents a string with a newline character.

Comment: This is just a representation. If you print individual list elements, you will see in your desired form.

Comment: Thank you both of you. You help me to learn more about string

Comment: Change all the path characters from `'\\'` to `'//'`

Answer (score 1):

`\` is an "[escape character](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)". It means the next character is "special". It allows strings to contain special characters that would otherwise be difficult to represent. For example `\n` means "linefeed" and `\t` means "horizontal tab". So how to do represent a single `\`? You use `\\`, which means literally `\`.

`\` was picked because it's an unusual character. Unfortunately, way back in 1981, Microsoft picked `\` as their path delimiter for MS-DOS. Nearly 40 years later Windows maintains that tradition, so Windows paths often get decorated with multiple `\` characters. The trick is to only escape once - so when creating a string, `\` should turn into `\\` to protect it. From there it should not be escaped again. When you see `\\\\` the escaping has been performed twice.